# testing code on time interval

Tags: java

Hi I want to run code over a time period. For example i would like my code to do something like this.

```
for(every 5 minutes until i say to stop)
 automatically read in new value for x
 automatically read in new value for y

if (x==y)
     //do something

if (x!=y)
     //do something else
```

Comment: first of all, you should use if (x==y) {...} else {...} instead

Answer (score 3):

[Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Naive version. You might consider `Timer` or the [quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) instead.

```
while (!done) {
   try {
     Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
     x = readX();
     y = readY();
     if (x == y) {

     } else {

     }
   } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.currentTimeMillis(); Returns you the system time in milliseconds, you can use that.
but first, you need some sort of loop.
This is an alternative to Timer 's

```
public static final int SECONDS = 1000;
public static final int MINUTES = 60 * SECONDS;

boolean quit = false; //Used to quit when you want to..
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while (!quit) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= (startTime + (long)5*MINUTES)) {
        //automatically read in new value for x
         //automatically read in new value for y

        if (x==y) {
            //do something
        } else {
        //do something else
        }
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //reset the timer for the next 5 minutes
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a sleep or something in this?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do your processing here
    }
};

ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Call `service.shutdown()` when you want to stop.